# What does this expression mean on the ipfiltering project?

Tags: c#

I have seen the expression:

```
configuration.Filters.Select(f=> Create(f)).ToArray());
```

Im wondering what the `f => Create(f)` means? Is this a `Lambda`? And why is it in a `Select` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).
The [`Select` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) takes a delegate as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a lambda expression. It's in a select clause as a *projection*. The lambda expression is executed for each item from `configuration.Filters`, and the result is then passed on to the next stage. It's hard to know exactly what that means in this case without knowing what `Create` does, but as an example, you might have:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] squares = values.Select(x => x * x);
                      .ToArray();

// Now squares is { 1, 4, 9 }
```

This is part of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) (at least, I assume it is - it's just possible that you're calling a completely different `Select` method). LINQ is a big topic, but well worth exploring - fortunately there are plenty of tutorials and books around.

Comment: Hi Jon ok I cant actually get your code to compile. Am I missing a using reference?

Comment: @Pete2k: You may be missing a reference to the System.Core assembly, or a using statement for the System.Linq namespace.